# Concisely deep copy a slice?

Tags: go, deep-copy

In Go, what's a concise/well-performing way to deep copy a slice? I need to copy the slice to a new backing array, because the other array is owned by something else and may be modified after the copy.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
copy := append([]T{}, orig...)
```

where `T` is the element type of `orig`.

Comment: Cannot be done in a general way. Deep copies are hard in a language with recursive types and recursive data structures and pointers. What is the deep copy of a pointer, a slice, a slice of pointers, a pointer to a slice of pointers? Now sprinkle reflect.Value's...

Comment: Perhaps I've misused the term deep copy, but I did mention that I want to copy the storage for the backing array. That is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem the fastest way is to append to a slice with the necessary space. I've extended @Anisus answer with the benchmark results, and the resulting fastest solution.

```
BenchmarkCopy            100000 18240 ns/op
BenchmarkAppend          100000 18276 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendPreCapped 100000 16407 ns/op
```

BenchmarkAppendPreCapped is likely avoiding zeroing and/or growing of the slice. It looks like so:

```
copy := append(make([]T, 0, len(orig)), orig...)
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your benchmark results. Please post your benchmark code.

Answer (score 35):

Not sure which solution is fastest without a benchmark, but an alternative is using the built in `copy`:

```
cpy := make([]T, len(orig))
copy(cpy, orig)
```

From [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy):

> func copy(dst, src []Type) int
>
> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a
>   destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a
>   string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may overlap.
>   Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum
>   of len(src) and len(dst).

**Note**

The solution will copy all the values in the slice. If the slice contains pointers or structs with pointer fields, these pointer values will still point to the same values as the `orig` slice.

**Benchmark**

Benchmarking the two options, you can see they have very similar performance.

```
BenchmarkCopy     100000         24724 ns/op
BenchmarkAppend   100000         24967 ns/op
ok      benchmark   5.478s
```

This is the benchmark code:

package main

```
import "testing"

var result []T

const size = 10000

type T int

func BenchmarkCopy(b *testing.B) {
    orig := make([]T, size)

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        cpy := make([]T, len(orig))
        copy(cpy, orig)
        orig = cpy
    }
    result = orig
}

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    orig := make([]T, size)

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        cpy := append([]T{}, orig...)
        orig = cpy
    }
    result = orig
}
```

I am not sure when/if the zero-fill is performed. But if you look at the assembly, in the append version you will have:

```
CALL    ,runtime.growslice(SB)
```

while the copy will call:

```
CALL    ,runtime.makeslice(SB)
```

and I would guess that both of these calls performs the zero-fill.

Comment: I get the feeling this will zero cpy, and then copy over it. I hope to avoid the zero by creating a slice with the necessary cap and appending to it.

Comment: @MattJoiner: I made a benchmark to see if the two performed differently, but it seems not. I've edited the answer with the benchmark.

Comment: What's up with all the slice assignments? Great work. I'll run this benchmark myself.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. Thanks for the great work.

Answer (score 6):

```
slicecopy := append([]T(nil), slice...)
```

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type T int
    slice := make([]T, 8)
    for i := range slice {
        slice[i] = T(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(slice), cap(slice), &slice[0], slice)
    slicecopy := append([]T(nil), slice...)
    fmt.Println(len(slicecopy), cap(slicecopy), &slicecopy[0], slicecopy)
}
```

Output:

```
8 8 0x10322160 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
8 8 0x103221a0 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

References:

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

```
// Make a copy of a slice (of int).
slice3 := append([]int(nil), slice...)
fmt.Println("Copy a slice:", slice3)
```

---

Benchmarks:

```
package main

import "testing"

var result []T

const size = 1000

type T int

func BenchmarkCopy(b *testing.B) {
    orig := make([]T, size)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        cpy := make([]T, len(orig))
        copy(cpy, orig)
        orig = cpy
    }
    result = orig
}

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    orig := make([]T, size)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        cpy := append([]T{}, orig...)
        orig = cpy
    }
    result = orig
}

func BenchmarkAppendPreCapped(b *testing.B) {
    orig := make([]T, size)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        cpy := append(make([]T, 0, len(orig)), orig...)
        orig = cpy
    }
    result = orig
}

func BenchmarkAppendNil(b *testing.B) {
    orig := make([]T, size)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        cpy := append([]T(nil), orig...)
        orig = cpy
    }
    result = orig
}

func main() {}
```

Output:

```
$ go version
go version devel +ffe33f1f1f17 Tue Nov 25 15:41:33 2014 +1100 linux/amd64
$ go test -v -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkCopy                   200000        9983 ns/op
BenchmarkAppend                 200000       10004 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendPreCapped        200000       10077 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendNil              200000        9960 ns/op
ok      so/test 8.412s
$ go test -v -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkCopy                   200000       10000 ns/op
BenchmarkAppend                 200000       10112 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendPreCapped        200000        9892 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendNil              200000       10005 ns/op
ok      so/test 8.422s
$ go test -v -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkCopy                   200000        9967 ns/op
BenchmarkAppend                 200000        9898 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendPreCapped        200000       10123 ns/op
BenchmarkAppendNil              200000       10022 ns/op
ok      so/test 8.424s
$
```