# Go: nested loop causes scope issue

Tags: loops, go, multidimensional-array, scope

I have some code in golang which is suppose to discover the next possibilities in a Tic-Tac-Toe board.
This is the buggy part:

```
var next []State
    for row := 0; row < len(board); row++ {
        for place := 0; place < len(board[row]); place++ {
            if board[row][place] == 0 {
                nPos := board
                fmt.Print(nPos)
                
                nPos[row][place] = play
                fmt.Print(nPos, row, place, play, "\n")
                next = append(next, nPos)
            }
        }
    }
```

`State` is a type of `[][]int`.
`board` is a `State`, `play` is an `int` and `next` is a `[]State` .

The output is as follows:

```
[[0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]][[1 0 0] [1 0 0] [1 0 0]] 0 0 1
[[1 0 0] [1 0 0] [1 0 0]][[1 1 0] [1 1 0] [1 1 0]] 0 1 1
[[1 1 0] [1 1 0] [1 1 0]][[1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]] 0 2 1
[[[1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]] [[1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]] [[1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]]]
```

You can clearly see two things:

1. One iteration changes the whole column (I guess it has to do with the outer loop, `row`)
2. For some reason the changes are saved (nPos is not reinitialized through iterations)

I am somewhat new to Go, am I wrong when expect nPos to be a new variable in every iteration?

I have already looked for issues in the line `nPos[row][place] = play`, but apparently no specific line causes the issue. I guess it is just the scope.

Comment: `nPos := board` <--- here both `nPos`, and `board` contain the same slice, Go does not implicitly do a deep slice copy. If you want a duplicate of a slice - you should manually clone it.

Comment: What zerkms said. You can also use arrays instead of slices (`[3][3]int`), then assignment copies everything.

Answer (score 0):

As @zerkms pointed out:
`nPos := board` <--- here both nPos, and board contain the same slice, Go does not implicitly do a deep slice copy. If you want a duplicate of a slice - you should manually clone it.
One option is:
`cpy := make([]T, len(orig)) copy(cpy, orig)`

Other answers are here:
[Concisely deep copy a slice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055626/ddg#27056295)